# luabind: Can't call basic lua functions like print, tostring

Tags: c++, lua, environment, luabind

A very basic question i guess:

The C++ code, calling lua looks like this:

```
lua_State* m_L;
m_L = lua_open();
luabind::open(m_L);
luaL_dofile(m_L, "test.lua");
try {
    luabind::call_function<void>(m_L, "main");
} catch (luabind::error& e) {
    std::string error = lua_tostring(e.state(), -1);
    std::cout << error << std::endl;
}
lua_close(m_L);
```

now test.lua has the following contents:

```
function main()
print "1"
end
```

Upon execution I receive the error:

```
test.lua:2: attempt to call global 'print' (a nil value)
```

What is the problem? It has something to do with environments? I thought functions like print are defined in the global environment. Why is it not found then?

Thank you very much.

Comment: ok i figured it out: luaopen_base(m_L); needs to be called after lua_open()

Comment: you'll need to call luaopen_string(m_L), luaopen_math(m_L), etc to open the appropriate built in lua libraries, if you plan on using those as well.

Comment: @chris.schuette: You should either answer your own question and accept that answer (thus marking the question as being finished) or delete the question.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't think I can answer my own questions yet - I think my reputation is too low. Do you think it would be appropriate to delete this question? Maybe someone will find this info here valuable...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you figured it out, you have to call `luaopen_base` to get `print` and other base functions. Then you need to call `luaopen_string`, `luaopen_math`, to get the basic modules and functions in. Instead of writing it all out manually, can load all Lua base function at once with [`luaL_openlibs`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_openlibs):

```
lua_State* m_L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(m_L);
```